# Latest gridgain is java- (as opposed to scala-) based?

Tags: gridgain

I had been following GridGrain since 2010 - they have been a pioneer in enterprise scale distributed processing systems implemented in scala.

More recently they had open sourced the core platform.  I pulled from github and found .. v little scala. The core packages are all in java.

Nikita (the CEO) had been seesawing on scala vs java in the past two years Is this the end result then - that the core code is in java?  I am for various reasons more interested in the scala code at this time and wondering if there were any plans to resume/revive the scala based platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridGain has always had core code written in Java. However, GridGain does have Scala DSL, called Scalar, that you can find on GitHub: https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain/tree/master/modules/scalar.  Also GridGain management console is written in Scala as well: https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain/tree/master/modules/visor-console

Comment: Really?  "Back in the day" in 2010 the core code was in java?

Comment: @javadba Yes, GridGain core has always been written in Java.